# How to split across multiple divs while keep the formating, then addClass to divs over max characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code currently wraps each word with a div by splitting it with the space and adds a class which has a grey background.

I want to keep this styling, but set a character count. That at '**26**' if happens to be inside a word, it'll choose to split before that word and add `.overMax` with an orange background to all words over the character limit.

Currently the words are:

```
Samsung Galaxy S20+5GS Black (345) Smartphone
```

Splitting at 26 would make it:

```
Samsung Galaxy S20+5G S Bl
```

Desired output:

```
Samsung Galaxy S20+5G S
```

Keep in mind all the `.splitDIVtitle` div's should also remain around their current words.

Final HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="title-editable" contenteditable="true" data-size="-2">
    <div class="splitDIVtitle">Samsung</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle">Galaxy</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle">S20+5G</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle">S</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle overMax">Black</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle overMax">(345)</div>
    <div class="splitDIVtitle overMax">Smartphone</div>
</div>
```

```js
// Find spaces, wrap words with div.splitDIVtitle
let get_gtTitle = document.getElementById("title-editable").textContent;
let split_gtTitle = get_gtTitle.split(' ');

// Removes any duplicates found (e.g in example Samung)
const notduplicates = split_gtTitle.filter((item, index) => index == split_gtTitle.indexOf(item) && item !== "");

const mainDiv = document.getElementById('title-editable');
mainDiv.innerText = ""
notduplicates.forEach(item => {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.classList.add('splitDIVtitle');
  div.innerHTML = item;
  mainDiv.appendChild(div)
})

let length_GTEditableTitle = $("#gumtree-title-editable").text()
.length;
let length_GTSetMax = 26;
if (length_GTEditableTitle < length_GTSetMax) {
    // Add .overMax here if .splitDIVtitle falls 'within' or 'outside' of 26
    // Which would be: Samsung Galaxy S20+5G S Bl
    // Decided Output should be: Samsung Galaxy S20+5G S
    // This should be done without breaking the div.splitDIVtitle's that have been added
}
```

```css
.splitDIVtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.overMax {
  background: orange !important;
}
#example { 
  padding-top: 30px 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-editable" contenteditable="true" data-size="-2">
  Samsung Galaxy S20+5G Samsung S Black (345) Samsung Smartphone
</div>
```

How can I do this? I can do it without divs inside the divs. But keeping the styling/classes is what is killing me.

Comment: The description of your required output and the demo HTML you've shown of it do not agree. The description says you want the `.overMax` class on each extra word past 26 characters, yet the demo HTML has all words wrapped in the single `.overMax` div...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the spot, not sure how I missed that haha. Properly in a rush to get my question out before shopping >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can loop through the array of words and keep a running count of the number of characters used in each entity within the array. If that count goes over the 26 character limit, then add the `overMax` class to the current `div`.

```js
// jQuery version
$('#title-editable').html((i, html) => {
  let characterCount = 0;
  let response = [];
  console.log([...new Set(html.trim().split(' '))]);
  [...new Set(html.trim().split(' '))].forEach((word, i) => {
    response.push(`<div class="splitDIVtitle ${(characterCount + i > 26 ? 'overMax' : '')}">${word}</div>`)
    characterCount += word.length;
  });
  return response;
});

// Plain JS version
/*
  let title = document.querySelector('#title-editable');
  let characterCount = 0;
  let response = [];
  [...new Set(title.innerHTML.trim().split(' '))].forEach((word, i) => {
    response.push(`<div class="splitDIVtitle ${(characterCount + i> 26 ? 'overMax' : '')}">${word}</div>`)
    characterCount += word.length;
  });
  title.innerHTML = response.join('');
*/
```

```css
.splitDIVtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.overMax {
  background: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-editable" contenteditable="true" data-size="-2">
  Samsung Galaxy S20+5G Samsung S Black (345) Samsung Smartphone
</div>
```

Comment: I love how you gave me both jQuery and Javascript option. Could you please just edit this to include removal of duplicates so I can award you it. Amazing work! thx

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer with a method of how you can do that using a `Set()`

Comment: Thank you, but I think that is effecting your code, as now .overMax isn't applied to all div's over 26 characters, just the last one? As Black and (345) aren't orange when I hit run code. I didn't know about Set() thank you for that.

Comment: It did, however the calculation didn't include spaces. I've edited it so that now it does.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just keep track of the number of characters seen so far?

```
let character_count = 0
notduplicates.forEach(item => {
  ...
  character_count += (item.length + 1)
  if (character_count > 26) {
      div.classList.add('overMax');
  }
  ...
})
```

```js
// Find spaces, wrap words with div.splitDIVtitle
let get_gtTitle = document.getElementById("title-editable").textContent;
let split_gtTitle = get_gtTitle.split(' ');

// Removes any duplicates found (e.g in example Samung)
const notduplicates = split_gtTitle.filter((item, index) => index == split_gtTitle.indexOf(item) && item !== "");

const mainDiv = document.getElementById('title-editable');
mainDiv.innerText = ""
let character_count = 0
notduplicates.forEach(item => {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.classList.add('splitDIVtitle');
  character_count += (item.length + 1)
  if (character_count > 26) {
      div.classList.add('overMax');
  }
  div.innerHTML = item;
  mainDiv.appendChild(div)
})
```

```css
.splitDIVtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.overMax {
  background: orange !important;
}
#example { 
  padding-top: 30px 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-editable" contenteditable="true" data-size="-2">
  Samsung Galaxy S20+5G Samsung S Black (345) Samsung Smartphone
</div>
```